# Application crashing in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I am trying  two same statements and running them on iOS 5.1 simulator and on iOS 7 simulator but they both are returning different values and my code is

```
 BOOL isSelected = YES


     NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
```

On debugging in respective simulators:

while running on iOS 5.1 simulator :

```
selectedIndex = (null)
```

while running on iOS 7 simulator :

```
selectedIndex = @"1"
```

and if I try :

```
isSelected = NO:
```

On debugging in respective simulators:

while running on iOS 5.1 simulator :

```
selectedIndex = (null)
```

while running on iOS 7 simulator :

```
selectedIndex = @"0"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could be one of those fiddly thing you need to wrap in another constructor.

simulators never quite get it right.

Comment: So where's the crash?

Comment: I am adding selected index in a dictionary there i get a crash...

Comment: Not really sure what it is you're trying to accomplish. If you are having issues there may be another solution?

Comment: @Vikas: The crash happens when you add a `nil` reference to the dictionary. Your two lines of code are completely sane, so you must be omitting other code here that explains why the value doesn't make it to the NSNumber correctly.